# Why was the Cassandra Context removed from DataStax Enterprise 4.7

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I came to know from this [link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkCCcontext.html) that Cassandra context was removed `DataStax Enterprise 4.7`. Does it mean it will be removed from `Spark Cassandra Connector`? Also, what is the reason for removing it. Is it performance related?

Answer (score 2):

### Cassandra Context

The 'CassandraContext' object was Datastax Only and never existed in the Spark Cassandra connector. It was basically a compiled mapping of Cassandra tables to Scala objects and case classes. It required compiling a new object every time the underlying schema of Cassandra changed and created a divergence with the OSS Spark Cassandra Connector API. The additional performance cost of creating this object was seen as a waste of time versus the limited convenience it offered. In addition, the code would only work in the spark shell so it was not suitable for prototyping code for stand alone applications.

### Edit: I was mistaken the Cassandra Context is a Separate structure than the CassandraSQLContext. My memory was wrong.

The `CassandraSQLContext`'s main purpose was to provide a persistent catalogue and automatic mapping to Cassandra tables from Spark when the system does not have a `HiveMetastore` present. When using the CassandraSqlContext the user is limited to a tiny subset of AnsiSQL as opposed to with a `HiveContext` which uses 99% of HiveQL. The code for the `CassandraSQLContext` is still present in the Connector and you are still able to create a `CassandraSQLContext` in DSE.

In Datastax Enterprise there is already a `HiveMetastore` written to work with Cassandra. The custom Metastore automatically registers all Cassandra tables as well so having the `CassandraSQLContext` was seen as being redundant, confusing, and less featured than it's Hive counterpart. To this end it is recommended that all users use a HiveContext instead of the CassandraSQLContext and we removed the automatic `cc` object from the shell.